# How to detect if the user submitted a form more than once?

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

In order to prevent "Spamming" and filling up the database with dummy data , I'm wondering if there is a way to check if the user submit a form more than once , Then I will show a Recaptcha .

So is it possible to do so? and is it possible to know even he changed his IP?

Comment: Do you store the IP upon submission of the form? You can check for multiple records at that point and return an error if there are too many existing submissions.

Comment: You cannot stop someone from submitting from another IP

Comment: you can create a cookie on submit. The next time the form is entered, you will see the cookie and you can tell them they have already submitted the form. They can manually delete the cookie or switch to incognito mode, but such tricks are not known to everyone